# View data form id column in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have two table in database classrooms and status. classroom fields  are `id`,`subject`, `class_code`, `user_id`. I make a link for every class. now i want to show data in my class view page for every class. If my class link `class?class_id=47` then its must be show only `class?class_id=47` data and if `class?class_id=55` its must be show `class?class_id=55` data but in my `class?class_id=55` class its shows class?class_id=47 class data.

My controller:

```
public function getclass(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->get('class_id'); if(Input::has('status-text'))
    {
        $text=e(Input::get('status-text'));
        $rules = [
        'status_text'=>'required|string',
        ];
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        if(Input::hasFile('status_image_upload'))
        {
            $rules['status_image_upload'] = 'image';
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
            if($validator->fails())
            {
                $image = $request->file('status_image_upload');
                $imageName = str_random(8).'_'.$image->getClientOriginalName();
                $image->move('status_images', $imageName);
                $userStatus = new Status();
                $userStatus -> class_id = $id;
                $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
                $userStatus -> image_url = $imageName;
                $userStatus -> type = 1;
                $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $userStatus -> save();
                Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
                return redirect(route('class',['class_id'=>$id]));
            }
        }
        else if ($validator->fails())
        {
            $userStatus = new Status();
            $userStatus -> class_id = $id;
            $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
            $userStatus -> video_url = $request['video_url'];
            $userStatus -> type = 2;
            $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $userStatus -> save();
            Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
            return redirect(route('class',['class_id'=>$id]));
        }
}return view('class',[
'posts'=>status::orderBy('id','DESC')->get()
])->with('class_id',$request->get('class_id'))
->with('classroom',classroomModel::find($id)->first());}
```

**My view**

```
<li>Subject-->{{$classroom->subject_name}}</li>
<li>Section-->{{$classroom->section}}</li>
```

What should to do for that?

Comment: yes. i am passing $id to the method

Comment: If don't mind you can see my code in team viewer also. my code is long.

Comment: my route. Route::any('/class',[
    'uses'=> 'classroom@getclass',
    'as'=>'class',
    ]);

Comment: I edit my post please see my controller in my post.

Comment: I will help to debug in it, put `dd($id);` after this line `$id = $request->get('class_id');` and check if you get the correct id from the url

Comment: Yes my id is correct.

Comment: How can i do this??

Comment: Sir can you solve this probem?

Comment: Hi I have looked at your code it needs debugging and it is time consuming. I will leave as is hope somebody spending more time on it.